# how convert base64 to json in android?

Tags: android, json, base64

i want to get data from a remote server, 
the return data is base64 encoded in json string.
i need to decode Base64 encoded data to fetch the json array. 
is any suggestion?
thanx

Comment: Is the data you have a string representing some JSON data, or is it base64 encoded JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use one of the `decode` methods of the [`Base64`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) class.

Something like:

```
String decoded = new String(Base64.decode(your_base64_input_data));
```

It's not quite clear from your question if/how JSON gets mixed in, so can't really help with that.